# Open source project for downloading mailing list archives preferably in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am interested in knowing if there are any open source projects (preferably in Python) which can be used to download (crawl?) the mailing list archives of open source projects such as Lucene/Hadoop (such as http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-java-user/). I am specially looking for a crawler/downloader customized for (Apache) mailing list archives (not a generic crawler such as Scrappy). Any pointers are highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's usually facilities for downloading mbox files. In the link you provided, you can for example append the mbox name and get the mail archive directly. Example, the mbox for October 2012:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-java-user/201210.mbox

So getting the archives programmatically is pretty straightforward. Once you have them:

```
import mailbox
mails = mailbox.mbox(filename.mbox)
for message in mails: print message['subject']
```

Comment: Thank you @JosefAssad. Which key holds 'content' of the message? I couldn't find a key for the content. However as_string() print everything, I was wondering if content alone was present in some key.

Comment: I can warmly recommend the python docs. Specifically, you want http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message . In the terminology of this module, the body is called the payload. Have a look at the function `get_payload`.

Comment: Thanks for the terminology. I wasn't aware that body is called 'payload'.